# How to check whether file content is empty , by traversing the array of filenames

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

i have a array of filenames , and i have to traverse this array and check whether the content of ALL the files is empty.

Here is the code

```
foreach my $reportFile (sort { getDateInName($b) <=> getDateInName($a)} @ReportFiles)
{
   my @fileData = readFile($reportFile);
   if(!@fileData)
   {
        outputLog("FAIL: File Doesnt Contain Any Data.");
        return;
   }
}
```

But in the code above, iam returning even if a single file is empty, 
I would like to know how can we check whether ALL the content of ALL files is empty and then return.

So I would like to return only if none of the files in the array has content.

Even if one file has content i wouldnt return

Thanks

Comment: What is `false`? Why are you comparing the result of `getDateInFileName` and `getDateInName` in the `sort` block?

Comment: @Borodin corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`List::Util::all`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util):

> Similar to `any`, except that it requires all elements of the `@list` to make the `BLOCK` return true. If any element returns false, then it returns false. If the `BLOCK` never returns false or the `@list` was empty then it returns true.

---

```
use List::Util 'all';

sub check_files {
  ...
  warn( "All files empty" ), return
    if all { -z } @_;
  ...
}
```

or

```
sub are_all_empty { all { -z } @_ }
```

Comment: This is good of course, but the posted code suggests that they would like to have a record on which files are empty/non-empty.  It makes sense that we'd like to know that, what in my mind makes clean and nice solutions far trickier. (Unless the recording in the posted code in fact isn't essential.)

Comment: @zdim if the individual status of each file is required then I'd do something like `map -z, @_;` and work with the resultant array.

Comment: Right, for example. Unfortunately it won't be as direct and clean.  In which case the loop might well be just as good.

Comment: Let the OP clarify their intent first. What do they want the code to do?

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you only want to check if a file is empty, you should not try to read it. This might be dangerous as you might ending up reading a huge file in memory. You can test for a file being empty like that `if (-s $reportFile) {...}`. Secondly, to fix the problem that you have with returning if any file is empty, you need to invert the logic of you code, i.e. you must check if any file is *not* empty. This is because of the following logical equivalence: saying that "all the files are empty" is the same as "no file is nonempty". Putting it all together, you get something like that:

```
sub all_empty {
    foreach my $reportFile (sort { getDateInFileName($b) <=> getDateInName($a)} @ReportFiles)
    {
       if (-s $reportFile) {
           return 0;
       }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: if (-s $reportFile) , will this check if all the files are not empty.
I would want ot return only if ALL the files are empty
Even if a single file out of 10000 files  has content , i would not return

Comment: @LearningCpp Yes, check the code again. The sub `all_empty` checks if all files are empty.

Answer (score -1):

Try to have a boolean flag, which is set to one if u have content in atleast one file, so that you do not have to traverse through the array and return as soon as u find a file with content
    And if there is no content in the file, go to next iteration to check if the content is avaialble.
    And come out of loop if content is present in any of the file

```
my $isFileEmpty = 0 ;
foreach my $reportFile (sort { getDateInFileName($b) <=> getDateInName($a)} @ReportFiles)
{
    my @fileData = readFile($reportFile);
   if(@fileData) {
      $isFileEmpty = 1;
      last;     
   }
   else {
      next ; 
    } 
}
if($isFileEmpty eq 0)
{

    return;

}


PS : Do you have content available in most of the cases ?
```